# Numpy arrays (append, concatenate)

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to add "average" to other numpy array "all averages", but append, concatenate returns with errors:

```
n1, n2, n3  = 5 , 16, 27
all_averages = np.array ([], dtype = float)
for i in range(1000):
    sample_2 = pareto.rvs (7, size = n1)
    average = np.array([np.average(sample_2)])
    all_averages.append(average)
```

'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

```
n1, n2, n3  = 5 , 16, 27
all_averages = np.array ([], dtype = float)
for i in range(1000):
    sample_2 = pareto.rvs (7, size = n1)
    average = np.array([np.average(sample_2)])
    np.concatenate((all_averages, average))
print(all_averages)
```

[]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy arrays are not like python lists, they have a fixed size. That's why you won't find an `append` method.

However, you're really close to the solution: `np.concatenate` does not work in-place, but **returns** the concatenate array. You should look around

```py
all_averages = np.concatenate((all_averages, average))
```

To be even more efficient, try to do only one `concatenate` operation. Store all averages in a list, and concatenate them all together afterwards. That way, you'll avoid unnecessary copies between arrays

```py
n1, n2, n3  = 5 , 16, 27
all_averages_list = []
for i in range(1000):
    sample_2 = pareto.rvs (7, size = n1)
    average = np.array([np.average(sample_2)])
    all_averages_list.append(average)
all_averages = np.concatenate(all_averages_list, axis=0) # check axis param, I'm not sure here
print(all_averages)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, in addition to @Grégoire Roussel you can do the same with `append()` which has the following signature: `numpy.append(arr, values, axis=None)`

Therefore, you'd have to do the following (last line changed):

```py
n1, n2, n3  = 5 , 16, 27
all_averages = np.array ([], dtype = float)
for i in range(1000):
    sample_2 = pareto.rvs (7, size = n1)
    average = np.array([np.average(sample_2)])
    all_averages = np.append(all_averages, average)
```

Comment: still, appending to a list is computationally expensive. I'd suggest to define the array with a needed size  a priori and then _fill_ the array.